# Adding RGB attributes to voxel

Tags: lidr, rgb, voxel

How can I add the `RGB` attributes to a voxel object?

The idea is to give `RGB` to the `color`argument inside the `plot` function in `lidR`. And still have the attribute `Z` as the legend in the `RGL`window. The whole idea is to give sort of realistic colors to the 3D model.

```
LAS_vox_met = voxel_metrics(LAS_denoised, ~list(N = length(Z)), 0.05) # calculate voxel metrics
plot(LAS_vox_met , color="Z", colorPalette = terrain.colors(50), size = 1, bg = "white", voxels = T, legend = T)
```

This is what I have produced so far.

[image]

Comment: Does the point-cloud contain RGB attributes?

Comment: Yes, the point cloud contains RGB values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for something like

```r
u = ~list(N = length(Z), R = mean(R), G = mean(G), B = mean(B))
LAS_vox_met = voxel_metrics(LAS_denoised, u, 2)
plot(LAS_vox_met , color="RGB", colorPalette = terrain.colors(50), size = 1, bg = "white", voxels = T, legend = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Notice that `voxels = TRUE` is a new feature in development in `v3.2.0` and not released on CRAN yet. It is better not asking questions that include stuff in development here. In this question it is not a big deal because the question works also without `voxels = TRUE`